# Как настроить редирект?

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal

Как настроить 301 редирект с домена:
Test-Test.ru на домен test-test.ru
Через файл htaccess или можно через php.

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться [генератором](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/redirect-generator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Никак не настраивать. Домен один и тот же, все запросы будут приходить на test-test.ru

В случае разных доменов так и настроить

```
Redirect / https://test-test.ru/
```

Comment: может там есть какой-то  глубинный смысл, например, код сайта привязан к директории, которая содержит имя домена, и в случае несовпадения регистрозависимая ФС не находит путь. (к вопросу о том, откуда вообще могла родиться такая задача)

Comment: Seo специалист, говорит что это нужно для того, чтобы избавиться от дублей сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Через `php`:

```
<?php
header("Location: https://new-url.ru");
exit;
```

[Подробнее](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)

В `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://url-new.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

[Подробнее](https://q-seo.com.ua/blog/301-redirect/)

Comment: в обоих вариантах ошибки, рабтать не будет

Comment: @Ипатьев исправил ошибки

Comment: Намекаю: редирект с домена не означает только редирект с корня сайта.

Comment: и, кстати, каким местом тут REQUEST_URI?

Comment: @Ипатьев сорри, разобрался и исправил